# How to understand strange behavior of switch stament?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have this function

```
private function getCurrencyByCountry($country){
    switch($country){
        case "US": return "USD"; break;
        case "UA": return "UAH"; break;
        case "FR":
        case "DE":
        case "ES":
        case "IT":return "EUR";  break;
        default: return "USD-default";
    }
}
```

When I call this method with parameter "UA" this function return "USD-default".
Why?

Comment: do a `var_dump($country)` before the function call, it's definitely not `UA`

Comment: Are you certain of the value of `$country`?

Comment: As you are using `return` it would work without the `break;` too.

Comment: BTW: The `break` statement is redundant, because the `return` will leave the switch-case (and the function) anyway.

Comment: Does it work with other values? Check that you are passing a string. Check that the string is upper case. Check that it doesn't have any trailing spaces. You could modify the function to do a `strtoupper()` and a `trim()` on the string before the `switch` statement; that might help with a few of those points.

Comment: I understand my mistake. In country I have "UA\r\n" whilst "UA"

Comment: I use this `str_replace("\r\n","",$country);`

Comment: @Victor `trim(str_replace("\r\n","",$country));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use do `var_dump($country);` 
Before,

```
switch($country){
        case "US": return "USD"; break;
```

Because, I am pretty much sure, you are passing more than a "string" through the parameter.

---

**Alternatively**, something like this below will come in handy as it gets the job done too.

```
<?php 
function foo($country) {
    $value = array(); 

       switch($country){
            case "US": 
            $value = "USD"; 
            break;
         case "UA": 
             $value = "UAH"; 
             break;
         case "FR":
         case "DE":
         case "ES":
         case "IT": 
             $value = "EUR"; 
             break;
             default: $value = "USD-default";
    }

    if(!empty($value)){
        return $value; 
        }

}
```

`echo foo('Whatever...');`

Comment: I get this `string(4) "UA
"`

Comment: Maybe you are sending extra space too, because it should be `"UA"` not `"UA "`

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a space a long with the string according to your comment on `php NoOb`'s post. You can use the [trim](http://php.net/trim) function to `trim` the spaces from the string.

```
private function getCurrencyByCountry($country)
{
    $country = strtolower(trim($country));
    switch($country)
    {
        case "us":
            return "USD";

        case "ua":
            return "UAH";

        case "fr":
        case "de":
        case "es":
        case "it":
            return "EUR";

        default:
            return "USD-default";
    }
}
```

Comment: I had explained about the extra space issue **[24](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599088/how-to-understand-strange-behavior-of-switch-stament/15599120#comment22120301_15599120)** minutes before your answer, anyway +1 for the effort.